# ExtJS 5/6. How to make my custom object config attributes bindable?

Tags: extjs, binding

I have a custom object `A` with a config attribute `b`:

```
Ext.define('A', {

    config: {
        b: 1
    },

    constructor: function(config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
        return this;
    }
}) ;
```

I created a ViewModel:

```
viewModel: {
    data: {
        a: Ext.create('A')
    }
},
```

but this binding is not working:

```
items: [
    {
        xtype:'textfield',
        bind:'{a.b}'
    },
```

What am I doing wrong?
I wrote this fiddle with the example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27qp

-- Update:
I have minified the code, but I missed the fact that in my actual viewmodel I have an object with several config variables, and I am thinking about having it in the viewmodel and have it sync with the view. Like when you have a 'reference' in a component.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between property and config is that a property can be called with class instance whereas a config must be called with its setter and getter only when our class extends `Ext.Base`. (The `Ext.Base` class [constructor](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/src/Base.js.html) is just a placeholder. It's the `Ext.Component` constructor that does all the work for components. Therefore, if you extend your class from `Ext.Component`, the same code would work as required.)

Now, to make this code work, we will have to modify it like this:

```
Ext.define('A', {
  config: {
    b: 1
  },
  constructor: function (config) {
    this.initConfig(config);
    return this;
  }
});

var objA = Ext.create('A');

Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
  title: 'Example',
  viewModel: {
    data: {
        //a: Ext.create('A'),
        x: objA.getB(),
    }
  },
  width: 400,
  layout: 'vbox',
  items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    reference: 'mytextfield',
    bind: '{x}'
  }, {
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'show a.b value',
    handler: function (button) {
        alert(this.lookupViewModel().get('x'));
    }
  }]
}).show();
```

I have made changes to your [code](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27u5). Hope this is of some help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. Another issue that happens with your solution is that objA.getB() does not change when the textfield is updated. My blame, since I did not especify it in my question, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

[Ext.Class.config](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-config) used to automatically create getter and setter methods, but it doest create `A.b` class property itself, its still `A.config.b`.

The problem is that [Ext.mixin.Bindable](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.mixin.Bindable.html) `bind` or `publishes` internally uses [Ext.app.ViewModel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.app.ViewModel.html) generic `get(path)` and `set(path, value)` methods, not sertain getter and setter methods, so it tries to use exactly `A.b`, not `A.getB()`.

You have to add `b` property to class itself, not its `config`, or use [Ext.app.ViewModel.formulas](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.app.ViewModel.html#cfg-formulas).

Check [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27ta).

*Also you still can use `A.config.b` like `{xtype: 'textfield', bind: '{a.config.b}'}`*.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! With your approach it works perfectly too. I stick to the solution of extending `Ext.Component` because it ends neat, although I find your solution more "purist" (since my classes actually are not Components). I wish I could accept both answers. I upvote yours as "useful" and I will try to compensate.